# How to smooth out curved loop cuts of a knife tool?

Tags: smooth

[image]I am trying to get smooth, EVENLY curved lines for the dark grey and blue stripe materials on the fuselage. I only used shade smooth and auto smooth, and saw the damage/distortion that the subdivision modifier causes. Spent hours on this, and simply don't know what else to do. I used the knife tool to make a straight line/cut for the dark grey end section, then manually made the second cut using the nodes to create a curve for the blue stripe. For what I am trying to do, I need some way to get a smooth, accurate curve for ***Both*** cuts, and I can see that I will NEVER get what I want doing this manually. Is there a way to create a curve exactly how I want it and apply to the knife tool? Can't stand that boxy look....

Any advice for a beginner would be greatly appreciated.....

Comment: I'd use a Bezier Curve with the Knife Project tool for that. Set up the curve shape that you need using a Bezier Curve. Select your fuselage. Go into Edit mode and Ctrl-click the Bezier curve. Then use Mesh > Knife Project and check 'Cut Through' in the bottom-left corner of the viewport.

Comment: Thank you Sir!!! Will try it….

Comment: If you have problems comment here and I'll post a full answer.

Comment: Mr. Eason, I tried what you suggested….created the Bézier curve that I wanted then added subdivide to make it even more smooth but after I followed your steps, the curve on the fuselage STILL looks blocky and hand drawn. The orange curve next to the fuselage is perfect…exactly how I want it. sending a photo of this....

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and add the image into that with an explanation. You can't add it to a comment. I'd suggest sharing your Blend file too so that we can see what's going on. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Do you have an Instagram account? It’s easier for me to send multiple photos to that as opposed to this site, and I need to send several to respond…

Comment: Or Facebook? Either would be fine…

Comment: No. I don't use Facebook or Instagram.